# Converting a dict containing multiple nestet dicts into a .csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a dict in Python containing multiple nestet dicts and I want to write them into a csv file.

The dict looks something like this:

```
dict = {'case1':{'variant1':{'Name':['1','2','3'],'Values':[1,2,3],'Unit':['one','two','three']}},
                 'variant2':{'Name':['1','2','3'],'Values':[1,2,3],'Unit':['one','two','three']},
        'case2':{'variant1':{'Name':['1','2','3'],'Values':[1,2,3],'Unit':['one','two','three']}},
                 'variant2':{'Name':['1','2','3'],'Values':[1,2,3],'Unit':['one','two','three']}}
```

So multiple cases with different variants and each variant conatins three lists of corresponding names, values and units.
As stated before I want to convert this dict into a csv file, ideally in a way where the different cases an variant are easilly distinguishable. Since the csv is going to be used primarilly in Excel I'm going to give an example of how I imagined it could look in Excel. Ideal would be something like this:
[test_dict2csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRxvT.png)

I know how to write a single variant (so one set of names, values and units) into a csv the code for which looks like this:

```
keys = sorted(dict['case1']['variant1'].keys())
with open("test_output.csv", "w") as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=';')
   writer.writerow(keys)
   writer.writerows(zip(*[dict['case1']['variant1'][key] for key in keys]))
```

But I don't know how to add the next variants and cases in the same row some columns down.

If anyone has an idea I would be very grateful :)

Comment: In the sample output you provide, you have `3` records with `12` fields, because each list has 3 elements. Is that an assumption you can make on all your data (that all the lists will have the same number of elements)? Note that your sample dict has the key `variant2` twice, how would that be handled? Also please do not use `dict` as a variable name, as it is a python keyword, so in your snippet of code it is a variable but it is weird to read, as one expects `dict` to mean and do something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate one record per element, one element from each list, you can first flatten the dictionary, then write it like you do:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

dict_data = {
    "c1": {
        "v1": {
            "Name": ["s111", "s112", "s113"],
            "Values": [111, 112, 113],
            "Unit": ["11one", "11two", "11three"],
        },
        "v2": {
            "Name": ["s121", "s122", "s123"],
            "Values": [121, 122, 123],
            "Unit": ["12one", "12two", "12three"],
        },
    },
    "c2": {
        "v1": {
            "Name": ["s211", "s212", "s213"],
            "Values": [211, 212, 213],
            "Unit": ["21one", "21two", "21three"],
        },
        "v2": {
            "Name": ["s221", "s222", "s223"],
            "Values": [221, 222, 223],
            "Unit": ["22one", "22two", "22three"],
        },
    },
}


def flatten_dict(curr_dict, curr_key=""):
    new_dict = {}
    for new_key, value in curr_dict.items():

        if curr_key == "":
            combined_key = new_key
        else:
            combined_key = curr_key + "_" + new_key

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict.update(flatten_dict(value, combined_key))
        else:
            new_dict[combined_key] = value

    return new_dict


flat = flatten_dict(dict_data)
pprint(flat)


keys = sorted(flat.keys())
with open("test_output_all.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(keys)
    writer.writerows(zip(*[flat[key] for key in keys]))
```

(I only changed the dict to be clearer on which value was which, and have shorter key names, the structure is similar to yours).
This prints:

```
{'c1_v1_Name': ['s111', 's112', 's113'],
 'c1_v1_Unit': ['11one', '11two', '11three'],
 'c1_v1_Values': [111, 112, 113],
 'c1_v2_Name': ['s121', 's122', 's123'],
 'c1_v2_Unit': ['12one', '12two', '12three'],
 'c1_v2_Values': [121, 122, 123],
 'c2_v1_Name': ['s211', 's212', 's213'],
 'c2_v1_Unit': ['21one', '21two', '21three'],
 'c2_v1_Values': [211, 212, 213],
 'c2_v2_Name': ['s221', 's222', 's223'],
 'c2_v2_Unit': ['22one', '22two', '22three'],
 'c2_v2_Values': [221, 222, 223]}
```

And in the file:

```
c1_v1_Name;c1_v1_Unit;c1_v1_Values;c1_v2_Name;c1_v2_Unit;c1_v2_Values;c2_v1_Name;c2_v1_Unit;c2_v1_Values;c2_v2_Name;c2_v2_Unit;c2_v2_Values
s111;11one;111;s121;12one;121;s211;21one;211;s221;22one;221
s112;11two;112;s122;12two;122;s212;21two;212;s222;22two;222
s113;11three;113;s123;12three;123;s213;21three;213;s223;22three;223
```

If you absolutely need the header like the one in your picture,
some preprocessing of the header line should be doable, to print each nested level on a separate line.

Cheers!